# How do I configure custom regions?

Tags: 7, display-suite

I have a page where I set to show a 'Two column stacked layout'. So I assigned a block of links on the left region. On the right region, I will use Context to show the respective custom block based on the parameter passed from the link that user click. 
[image: Manage Display]

But in Context, only the template's region are displayed but not those listed in the Display Suite. So how do I show hide the blocks in that "additional" region? 
[image: Context]